# Pourquoi le mot « interview » est masculin ou féminin ?

Tags: usage, étymologie, genre

Il semblerait que le mot « interview » peut être employé au masculin comme au féminin ([source sur Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/interview/43894)).

Savez-vous pourquoi ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C'est un nom anglais, donc neutre dans sa langue d'origine, qui n'a pas de marque lexicale (comme une terminaison en *-tion*) incitant à le considérer comme féminin.  La pratique dans ce cas est de donner le genre masculin en français, mais la proximité avec *entrevue* (dont il dérive même si le sens s'est spécialisé) fait qu'il a été utilisé avec les deux genres dès le début de son emprunt.  Voir la note historique du [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/interview).

Comment: On peut remarquer que le TLFi décrit le mot comme féminin. C’est également ce que j’ai constaté à l’usage. J’apprend d’ailleurs en lisant la question qu’il a parfois été masculin.

Comment: @Édouard, j'avais remarqué mais je connais des personnes qui l'emploient au masculin.  Je me demande si la réalité de l'usage n'est pas intermédiaire entre le Larousse qui a l'air de dire que les deux sont communs et le TLFi qui décrit presque le masculin comme une hésitation lors de l'emprunt, hésitation maintenant résolue en faveur du féminin.

Comment: Mon juge de paix (le petit Robert) indique : "n.f. - 1872; mot angl., du fr. *entrevue* ; Anglicisme . . ."

Answer (score 0):

**Quel besoin de réimporter un mot français** sous une orthographe légérement différente (entreveuë en moyen français - d'où, d'ailleurs la prononciation anglaise), sans aucune spécification supplémentaire de sens ? [temporairement, il a été réservé à une conversation tenue devant un journaliste]

Le français a aussi : conversation, entretien, conférence, pourparlers, colloque, conciliabule, tête-à-tête, dialogue, discussion, échange, causerie, et aussi causette, parlote, ainsi que l'obsolète devis qui signifiait un entretien familier.

Comment: On peut le regretter, mais le fait est que le mot interview est entré dans la langue : la question de son genre est légitime. Et votre réponse n’y répond guère, d’où mon vote négatif.